# Convert ASCII Characters to Mathematica Input Form

Tags: string-manipulation, symbols, conversion, input-forms

I have the following pure ASCII character list:

```
list ={"a", "\\:1d62", "\\:2081", "\\[Beta]", "\\:2081", " ", "+", " ", \
"a", "\\:1d62", "\\:2082", "\\[Beta]", "\\:2082", " ", "+", " ", ".", \
".", ".", " ", "+", " ", "a", "\\:2099", "\\:2081", "\\[Beta]", \
"\\:2099", " ", "=", " ", "b", "\\:1d62"}
```

How can I convert it to Mathematica Input Form ?

I tried: `FromCharacterCode[ToString[#, "ASCII"] &/@list`

But it does not work.

Comment: You should be converting hex to decimal first before applying `FromCharacterCode[]`: `FromCharacterCode[16^^1d62]`

Comment: Or `ToExpression["\\:1d62"]`.

Comment: Do you want the output to be symbols or strings? Should it be `a` or `"a"`? Should it be `\[Beta]` or "\[Beta]"? I assume it should be strings, otherwise you will have a mixture of strings and symbols, since there is no expression that matches " " or "+".

Comment: @CarlWoll The answer to this question is exactly what I was looking for.  Do you think that one could use this to automate this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183981/convert-math-in-text-form-to-latex-form?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Rohit suggests in the comments, one possibility is to use [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression). However, to be safer, one might want to use [`Symbol`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Symbol) instead. So:

```
Replace[
    list,
    a_ /; StringLength[a] > 1 :> Check[SymbolName @ Symbol[a], $Failed],
    {1}
] //InputForm
```

> {"a", "ᵢ", "₁", "β", "₁", " ", "+", " ", "a", "ᵢ", "₂", "β", "₂", " ", "+", " ", ".", ".", ".", 
>    " ", "+", " ", "a", "ₙ", "₁", "β", "ₙ", " ", "=", " ", "b", "ᵢ"}

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This looks great ! Do you think that you could apply this to this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183981/convert-math-in-text-form-to-latex-form?noredirect=1&lq=1